How is this frame size computed for a TextView
I've got the following xib: (minimal example stripped from a larger UI)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.Cocoa.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="11762" systemVersion="16D32" targetRuntime="MacOSX.Cocoa" propertyAccessControl="none">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="macosx"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.CocoaPlugin" version="11762"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <customObject id="-2" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="AboutWindowController"/>
        <customObject id="-1" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="FirstResponder"/>
        <customObject id="-3" userLabel="Application" customClass="NSObject"/>
        <window id="5">
            <rect key="contentRect" x="641" y="589" width="538" height="337"/>
            <view key="contentView" id="123">
                <rect key="frame" x="1" y="1" width="523" height="188"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                <subviews>
                    <textView id="28">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="523" height="188"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    </textView>
                </subviews>
            </view>
        </window>
    </objects>
</document>

After compilation, the NSTextView gets NSFrameSize with the height of 337, but I'd like to understand why. Why is it getting the height from the contentRect and not the frame of the view? Is there a specific documentation link I can find about it?
I found it surprising since this structure:
        <window id="5">
            <windowStyleMask key="styleMask" titled="YES" closable="YES"/>
            <rect key="contentRect" x="641" y="589" width="538" height="337"/>
            <rect key="screenRect" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="1440" height="877"/>
            <view key="contentView" id="6">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="538" height="337"/>
                <subviews>
                    <textField verticalHuggingPriority="750" preferredMaxLayoutWidth="0.0" id="13">
                        <rect key="frame" x="190" y="288" width="158" height="29"/>

does result in the height/width defined in the frame rect. (NSFrame is {190, 288}, {158, 29})

How do you instantiate the window? Post a [mre] please.

@Willeke this is not related to application code. I'm asking about the value compiled into the resulting nib file. This is the minimal example.

NSTextView is usually used inside a NSScrollView and your xib can't be created in IB, maybe it's an unsupported configuration. NSTextView resizes itself at runtime, is the frame size in the nib a problem?

How do you compile the xib?

@Willeke ah! that's good info, thank you - if it can't be created in IB, then I don't necessarily care about this edge case. I'm doing basic ibtool --compile the.nib the.xib
